# Obtener el numero de semana en Oracle

Tags: delphi, sql-server-2014, oracle-19c

Me encuentro trabajando con Delphi XE7 con FireDAC y con conexión a Oracle 19c y SQL Server 2014, necesito obtener los mismos resultados con ambos gestores para la función escalar WEEK, que obtiene el número de semana del año con un valor de 1 a 53, las consultas que se realizan son las siguientes:

```
SQL Server:
SELECT DATEPART(WEEK, '2020-10-05') Resultado: 41

Oracle:
SELECT TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR(TO_TIMESTAMP('2021-01-01'), 'WW')) Resultado: 40
```

Los resultados son distintos por lo cual quisiera saber de una manera para obtener el mismo resultado, investigando encontré que en Oracle con IW se obtiene la semana ISO pero al realizar pruebas con la fecha 2021-01-01 SQL Server me devuelve 1 y Oracle 53, espero que sepan de alguna manera de lograr que Oracle me devuelva el mismo numero de semana que SQL Server, en ambos gestores se tiene la configuración de que el primer día de la semana sea Lunes y el lenguaje en Español

Comment: probaste con otros datos o sólo con ese? Un año tiene 52 semanas, así que esa podría ser una excepción a controlar y podrías usar la aproximación que encontraste

Comment: Si probé con otros, un año puede tener 52 o 53 semanas, este año tiene 53, el 2021 tiene 52

Answer (score 0):

Si estás utilizando FireDAC, puedes utilizar las **"macro functions"**.
[Preprocesando commandos con FireDAC](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Preprocessing_Command_Text_(FireDAC))

La idea es que puedes utilizar algunas funciones que tiene FireDAC dentro de un Commando/SQL de forma que antes de ejecutarla, FireDAC sustituye esa función por la que necesita cada motor de Base de Datos con el que trabaja para que el resultado sea el mismo. De esa forma si se trabaja con más de un motor, ese trabajo lo puede hacer FD.

En tu caso concreto puedes utilizar funciones. Por ejemplo, puedes usar algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTab WHERE Year = {fn YEAR({fn NOW()}}
```

FireDAC, sustituirá las funciones `{fn YEAR}` y `{fn NOW}` por las correspondientes funciones del motor de SGBD que estés utilizando. De esta forma te abstraes de hacerlo tú.

Hay bastantes funciones que puedes utilizar y en concreto aquí tienes la lista de las referentes a **Fecha y Hora**.

[Date and Time Macro Functions (FireDAC)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/Date_and_Time_Macro_Functions_(FireDAC))

Entre ellas existe la función **WEEK(date_exp)**, que posíblemente sea lo que necesitas.

Comment: Gracias, si de hecho uso la macro función de FireDAC Week que me mencionas y es con ella con la que estoy obteniendo los resultados distintos, así como plasme mis ejemplos es como envía la consulta la macro función a los gestores